# How to differentiate the users and admin in the same dashboard in a django application?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am trying a django application which is having a login and dashboard.In the dashboard I am showing the details which are selected by the user at the time of registration that is working perfect but here the problem the admin can also login to the user dashboard in the dashboard it is showing all the details as blank but I want to show the phrase as no projects
This is my views.py :

```
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            if user.is_active:
                auth.login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('modsy:dashboard'))

        else:
            messages.error(request,'Invalid Credentials')
            # return render(request,'dashboard.html') ## removed 1
    # else: ## removed 2
    return render(request, 'login.html')

# This is a dashboard view
def dashboard(request):
    return render(request, 'index1.html')

# This is a account view
def account(request):
    return render(request, 'dashboard.html',);

# This is a logout view
def logout(request):
    messages.error(request,'You are now logged out')
    return render(request, 'login.html',);
```

dashboard.html:

```
<div class="container20 mt-4">
    <center>
      <h3 class="display-5 mt-2"><b>Account Details</b></h3>
    </center>
    <!--Your Account Details-->
    <h3 class="display-5 mt-5 ml-3"><u>Your Account Details</u></h3>
    <hr class="new1">
    <p class="p3 ml-4 mt-4"><b>Username: </b>{{request.user.project.user}}</p>
    <p class="p3 ml-4 mt-4"><b>Email: </b>{{user.email}}</p>
    <a href="account/edit/" class="button ml-2">Edit Profile</a>
    <a href="/" class="button ml-2">Messages</a>

    <hr class="new2">

    <!--Your Project-->
    <h3 class="display-5 mt-4 ml-3"><u>Your Project</u></h3>
    <hr class="new1">
    <!--Room-->
    <p class="p3 ml-4 mt-4"><b><u>ROOM</u>:<br></b>{{request.user.project.room}}</p>
    <hr class="new2">

    <!--Goals-->
    <p class="p4 ml-4"><b><u>GOALS</u>:</b>
      {% for goal in request.user.project.goal.all %}
      <br>{{goal}}
      {% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    </p>

    <hr class="new2">
    <!--Furniture-->
    <p class="p5 ml-4"><b><u>FURNITURE</u>:</b><br>{{request.user.project.furniture}}</p>
    <hr class="new2">

    <!--Designs-->
    <p class="p4 ml-4"><b><u>DESIGNS</u>:</b>
      {% for design in request.user.project.design.all %}
      <br>{{design}}
      {% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    </p>
    <hr class="new1">
  </div>
```

If admin logins to the dashboard he should be shown as the no projects message how can I achieve this?Please help me out

Comment: in your template you can check `{% if request.user.is_superuser %}`

Comment: @Nalin once see my template where should I keep this if statement

Comment: i think somewhere around ` <h3 class="display-5 mt-4 ml-3"><u>Your Project</u></h3>`

Comment: before this I should add right?

Comment: Then where should I write else part

Comment: Yes thank you I got it post it as an answer I will give upvote @Nalin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your template you can check if user is superuser or not.

```html
{% if request.user.is_superuser %}
    No Projects
{% else %}
    projects
{% endif %}
```